# Are multiple values from get_post_meta guaranteed to be ordered?

Tags: post-meta

You can create multiple rows in the `postmeta` table for a post with the same key, like this:

```
add_post_meta( $post_id, "example_key", "value1" );
add_post_meta( $post_id, "example_key", "value2" );
```

To retrieve the values, you can use `get_post_meta`, which will return an array:

```
$rv = get_post_meta( $post_id, "example_key" );
// $rv is array( "value1", "value2" )
```

Is the resulting array guaranteed to be ordered? In what order are the values in? Alphabetical, or date inserted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**.

`get_post_meta()` uses `get_metadata()` which in turn uses `update_meta_cache()` to retrieve the values. In the [source code](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_meta_cache/#source) we see this part (comment mine)

```
// $id_column is 'meta_id'
$meta_list = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT $column, meta_key, meta_value FROM $table WHERE $column IN ($id_list) ORDER BY $id_column ASC", ARRAY_A );
```

So the meta values will be ordered by `meta_id` in ascending order. Meaning, as @Jacob Peattie pointed out in comments, they will be **ordered by the date they were added**.

Comment: Small addition for clarity: This would then also be the order they were added.